# jQuery - Passing Text from File into a Value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass a number that may have a decimal point (eg. 7.5 or 90) that is being read from a text file and set it to a value.

```
function readFile() {
  jQuery.get('input.txt', function(txt) {
    $('#output').text(txt);
  });
}

$(function() {
  $("#gauge").dxCircularGauge({
    scale: {
      startValue: 0,
      endValue: 100,
      tickInterval: 1
    },
    value: $("#output"),
    title: {
      text: "Monthly Thermometer",
      horizontalAlignment: "center",
      verticalAlignment: "bottom",
      font: {
        size: 30,
        color: "#CFB53B"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I am finding that no matter what I try, it does not set the value to whatever number is in the text file (input.txt). I don't know much of what I'm doing but I'm trying to understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. please elaborate.

Comment: Where do you call `readFile()`?

Comment: Maybe it should be `value: $("#output").text(),`

Comment: Don't forget that `jQuery.get()` is asynchronous. The `dxCircularGauge()` function runs before it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand that the `$.get` function is making a GET request to the `input.txt` file and **when it get the response** it enters to the `function(x)` where `x` is the data obtained from that call (in your case, the number). All that call and response is asynchronous, so the code makes the call and continue executing the rest of the code without waiting the response. So, you are trying to create the `dxCircularGauge` widget before the response from the file has been received.

On the other hand, looking at the `DevExtreme` documentation, `value` has to be a number, and you're passing a jquery object.

Putting all together (you don't specify it, but I assume that `input.txt` file only contains the number)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get('input.txt', function(response) {

        $('#output').text(response);

        $("#gauge").dxCircularGauge({
            scale: {
                startValue: 0,
                endValue: 100,
                tickInterval: 1
            },
            value: parseFloat(response),
            title: {
                text: "Monthly Thermometer",
                horizontalAlignment: "center",
                verticalAlignment: "bottom",
                font: {
                   size: 30,
                   color: "#CFB53B"
                }
            }
        });
    },'txt');
});
```

What is important for you to understand is that any code you put after the `$.get` call is going to be executed inmediatly after **MAKING** the GET call ( without waiting the response), so you can't use the response data because you still don't have it. That's an asyncronous call.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear in the question, but yes input.txt only has a number in it. I just wanted the ticker on the gauge to point to the number/value in the input.txt file.

I did try the code you provided, but it results in a blank screen altogether.
Not sure what's wrong but perhaps it's just something that can't be done with this.

Comment: Are you getting any console error? If you put this line `alert(response);` before the line `$('#output').text(response);`, do you see the alert? what does it show?